# Asp NET Membership with MySql. Extending my_aspnet_applications table

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-membership

I'm using MySQL with ASPNET and Membership (including Entity Framework), also with autogenerateschema=true with no problem.
Currently we are in a stage where we are adding like 5 or 6 applications to my_asp_applications table and I'm wondering if I can extend this table with 2 o 3 more columns, like : "domain_name", "isActive", and some more.

Could be a problem when upgrading connector or dunno, somewhere in the near future? Will it crash if new membership stuff is added on MVC 4 when it's released? It is supposed to be used like that and extend or will be more safe to create another table?

I read a lot about modifying users table which seems ok to use profiles but I'm interested on the my_asp_applications table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review: [Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Providers: Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx)
The aspnet_Applications table is shared between providers (membership, roles,...).
I would not modify that table directly, but instead use another table and store your additional information there.